# If I'm downloading through a proxy on a virtual machine is my anonymity being jeopardized?

Tags: security, virtual-machine, proxy, privacy

I run a win7 VM on OS X. I am running it with vmare fusion.I have utorrent on my VM and it use a socks5 proxy (setup in the utorrent connection settings) for everything it downloads. Thats all I use, no VPN. Only socks5 proxy in utorrent. The VM is allowed connections through my OS X firewall, and utorrent is allowed connections through my windows (the VM) firewall. I don't want to expose my external IP of my router when downloading (except to proxy provider).

Comment: Where is this proxy?  What is your VM setup?  Which IP address are you concerned about exposing—the local IP of your main machine, the IP address of your VM, the external IP of a home NAT router?

Comment: You really should consider waiting for more answers before you accept one. The one you've accepted is pretty incomplete, and now that this question is answered, there won't be many people adding new answers.

Comment: @zigg see updated question

Comment: @PhilFrost Ill keep that in mind, sorry Im new around here :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I run a win7 VM on OS X. Could my external IP be seen because Im in a VM?

At least your VPN or proxy provider knows your external IP.  No way to avoid unless you want to connect via Tor, which you shouldn't do, or another proxy.

> I have utorrent on my VM and it uses the proxy for everything it download.

Does it also use the proxy to talk to the tracker, and also DHT?  It may be leaking your external IP via those.

DNS also may be leaking information you don't want logged.

> It is allowed connections through my OS X firewall.

To really harden your VM, you need:

- firewall rules that block everything except specifically allowed traffic.  Your specifically allowed traffic should be

  - the ports uTorrent uses, including DHT.
  - HTTP/HTTPS ports
  - DNS ports
  - the port that your VPN or proxy provider users
- firewall rules that not only restrict traffic by port, but also configure your firewall to block by source and destination address.

  - All outgoing traffic that doesn't go via your VPN or proxy provider IP addresses should be blocked.
  - All incoming traffic should be blocked except that which originates from your VPN provider.
- Make sure DNS is going through your VPN once it is up.

Comment: Not worried about the proxy provider knowing. I dont use the VPN service though. I only use the socks5 proxy when torrenting through utorrent (set up in the connection settings in utorrent). Also do you mean the firewall in my Windows VM or on on OS X

Comment: The firewall in OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer ...... **NO** 
A VM will show up as a separate machine on your network with its own ip and MAC address so any request sent by the VM is **VIA the PROXY**. This is why the VM **never** comes in contact with the **outside network**. Hence your anonymity is not jeopardized.

I have included a link with more information.
http://computer.howstuffworks.com/firewall4.htm

Comment: @zain27 I don't see how you could have answered this question so authoritatively without asking questions like I did in my comment.